# C++ istream operator>> bad-data handling

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Every time I ask a question here on SO, it turns out to be some very dumb mistake (check my history if you don't believe me), so bear with me if you can here.

It feels like my question should be very popular, but I couldn't find anything about it and I've run out of ideas to try.

Anyway, without further ado:

---

I'm trying to overload the input `operator>>`. It's supposed to read one **integer** at a time from a file, *skipping invalid data such as `char`s, `float`s, etc.*

Naturally, I'm checking `if(in >> inNum)` to both **get() the next token** and **check for successful get()**.
If successful, not much to say there.
If it fails, however, I assume that one of two things happened:

1. It stumbled upon a non-integer
2. It reached the eof

Here's how I tried to deal with it:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, SortSetArray& setB) {
    bool eof = false;
    int inNum = -1;
    while(!eof) {
        if(in >> inNum) {
            cout << "DEBUG SUCCESS: inNum = " << inNum << endl;
            setB.insert(inNum);
        }
        else {
            // check eof, using peek()
            // 1. clear all flags since peek() returns eof regardless of what
            //    flag is raised, even if it's not `eof`
            in.clear();
            cout << "DEBUG FAIL: inNum = " << inNum << endl;
            // 2. then check eof with peek()
            eof = (in.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof());
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

The file contains [1 2 3 4 a 5 6 7], and the program naturally goes into infinite loop.
Okay, easy guess, peek() doesn't consume the char 'a', and maybe `in >> inNum` also failed to consume it somehow. No biggie, I'll just try something that does.

And that's pretty much where I've been for the last 2 hours. I tried istream::ignore(), istream::get(), ios::rdstate to check eof, `double` and `string` instead of `char` in the file, just in case `char` is read numerically.

Nothing works and I'm desperate.

Weirdly enough, the approach above worked for a previous program where I had to read a triplet of data entries on a line of the format: `string` `int` `int`
The only difference is I used an `ifstream` object for that one, and an `istream` object for this one.

Bonus Question: inNum has the value of 0 when the hiccup occurs. I'm guessing it's something that istream::operator>> does?

Comment: use `in.clear();` to clear any error flags causing it and try it again. EDIT: also add `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to remove the character that is stuck in the stream

Comment: @Gasim I'm not sure what you mean. That's the first thing I did in the else{} body. Where else should I `clear()`?

Comment: @Kafeaulait You made correct placement of the `clear()` call. The only thing left to do is `ignore()` the offending character. If the file format is how you say (a line of space separated characters) all you have to do is `is.ignore();` to ignore that single character. Make sure this goes *after* the call to `clear()`.

Comment: @Gasim @0x499602D2 That worked. Though I had to ignore until `' '` is found instead of `\n` since my data are all on one line.
Weird enough, it didn't ignore anything when I tried an hour ago. The flags may have been affecting `ignore()` somehow and `clear()` did the trick. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Surely enough. Removing the `clear()` call is a headache. The program doesn't infinitely loop, which means eof is eventually reached, but the output contains no data from and beyond the offending character.  
I'm not even sure how that works.

Comment: You say "I assume", why aren't you stepping thru with the debugger?

Comment: @kfsone Oh. Assumptions are my way of saying "I'm pretty darn sure judging by the logic and I don't feel the need to actually verify this fact".
Sorry, communications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Implementation description**
>
> > 1. try to read an int
> > 2. if successful;
> >
> >    1. insert the read value to `setB`
> >    2. *next iteration*
> > 3. else;
> >
> >    1. clear error flags
> >    2. check so that we haven't reached the end of the file
> >    3. still more data? *next iteration*.

The above is the logic description of your function, but there's something missing...

In case we try to read a value, but fail, `std::istream`'s handle these cases by setting the approriate error flags, but it will not discard any data.

The problem with your implementation is that upon trying to read invalid data, you will just try to read the same invalid data again.. over, and over, and over, *inf*.

---

**Solution**

After clearing the error flags you can use [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to discard any data from the stream.

The function's *1st* argument is the max number of potential `char`s to ignore, and the *2nd* is the "if you hit this *char*, don't ignore any more*.

Let's ignore the maximum amount of characters, or until we hit `' '` (space):

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

in.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
```