# (C++) Why does this program stop taking input after an invalid input?

Tags: c++

I'm very new to all this, so please excuse me if I've made simple mistakes.

I was experimenting with a very simple C++ console program that takes three integer inputs, and then prints the sum. Could someone please explain to me why the program suddenly rushes to the end and stops taking the other input(s) when a non-integer value is entered?

For example, if I enter 5.5 as the first value. The decimal is dropped and variable "a" holds the value 5, but inputs for variables "b" and "c" are skipped. I would have imagined that the program would continue on normally after the conversion?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a{};
    std::cin >> a;
    int b{};
    std::cin >> b;
    int c{};
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << a + b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301679/cin-assigns-beginning-of-string-to-int-only-fails-in-second-call) for a similar example that asks the next question you'll might have after fixing this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ istream operator>> bad-data handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225782/c-istream-operator-bad-data-handling)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: Thank you all! My apologies for not finding these related posts. I was unsure how to word the search, and didn't encounter them.